# Basis for a subspace - error in book

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In Matrix Algebra by Gentle, it's stated that if $\mathcal B$ is a basis set for $\mathcal V$ and $\mathcal V_1\subseteq \mathcal V$, then there exists $\mathcal B_1$, with $\mathcal B_1\subseteq \mathcal B$, such that $\mathcal B_1$ is a basis set for $\mathcal V_1$ under a list of properties.

As a counterexample, suppose we are in $\mathbb R^3$ and the vector space $\mathcal V$ is the xy-plane. If $\mathcal V_1$ is the line $x=y, z=0$, this is a subspace of $\mathcal V$. Suppose the basis $\mathcal B=\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$. Then there is no $\mathcal B_1$ that is a subset of $\mathcal B$ such that it forms a basis for the line $x=y,z=0$.

Is my reasoning correct? I think it is, despite it being kind of a lame error.

Comment: Yes your reasoning is correct, it should be $B_1 \subset \text{vect}(B)=V$ (which is a trivial assertion)

Comment: Are those properties that you wrote about really properties? Perhaps they could be additional conditions?

Comment: Or could this be some version of the Exchange Lemma?

Comment: Where specifically is this stated in the book?

Comment: It's on page 22 [chapter 2] in a list of a few bullet points called 2.1.3.1 Properties of Basis Sets of Vector Subspaces. "There are several interesting facts about basis sets for vector subspaces and various combinations of the vector spaces. Verifications of these facts all follow similar arguments, and most are left as exercises." followed by bullet points.

Comment: @Stacker You are correct.

Comment: A simpler counter-example is $V=\Bbb R^2$ and $B=\{(1, 0),(0,1)\}$ and $V_1=\{(x,x):x\in \Bbb R\}.$